# OTA with contiki

Tags: microcontroller, ota, contiki-process

I want to perform the ota update process in our custom board of cc2538 uses contiki os. I found some information regarding this process. To add the contiki.oad.client library to the program file. But, I did not find the library like these.

Best Regards,
Kamalesh.C

How I will do these OTA process with our board. Is there any suggestion or documentation ?